# pep8 gives strange failures when typing module is combined with matplotlib or tensorflow

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, matplotlib, typing, pep8

I'm getting a strange errors when running `pep8` in Python2.7 on files using the `typing` module.

If I make a file `my_file.py` containing

```
import typing
import tensorflow
```

Then `py.test -k pep8 my_file.py` gives `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.  Removing either of the two imports, or reversing their order, stops the error.  This only seems to happen in `pep8`, not when running normally in Python.

It causes a different error with `matplotlib`:

```
import typing
import matplotlib
```

Here, `py.test -k pep8  pepcheck_file_a.py` gives `E   RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`.

As I mentioned, in either case, reversing the import order to:

```
import tensorflow
import typing
```

Stops the error.

It's annoying in a large codebase to have to make sure that typing is always imported *after* various other packages (one has to manually rearrange the imports in each file).

Is there some easier solution to this?